# Why can't I find System.Web.pdb on referencesource.microsoft.com?

Tags: c#, .net, debug-symbols, symbol-server, reference-source

```
SYMSRV:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols/System.Web.pdb/E6EBD6B61CEA407591438CC4E48036891/System.Web.pdb not found

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols: Symbols not found on symbol server.
SYMSRV:  System.Web.pdb from http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 131401 bytes 

http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Symbols downloaded from symbol server.
C:\Users\Micah\Symbols\System.Web.pdb\E6EBD6B61CEA407591438CC4E48036891\System.Web.pdb: Symbols loaded.
```

Notice how it was unable to find `System.Web.pdb` on `referencesource.microsoft.com`.  It found it on `msdl.microsoft.com` but those don't come with source files/lines.  I have downloaded the source code for `System.Web.dll` from `referencesource.microsoft.com` so I know the source is available.  It was my understanding that `referencesource.microsoft.com` was supposed to have PDBs for all released versions of the .NET Framework (including patches)?

The version of `System.Web.dll` that is currently being loaded is the 64-bit version found in the GAC marked as version `4.0.30319.34212`.  It has a release date of 5/29/2014.  As far as I know, it is the latest release of `System.Web.dll`, though if I am wrong on that I don't mind upgrading if it resolves this problem.

Comment: Micah, You can troubleshoot this with that team.  See: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html

Comment: Email sent.  Thanks.

Comment: Excellent!  Let us all know the resolution/answer you get!

Comment: Still not working in 4.6.  :(  I have sent in another report.  All other .NET Framework symbols load except System.Web and System.Data.

Comment: A reply from Microsoft regarding this issue: "You can expect to see reference sources and symbols published together with the RTM version of .NET 4.6 Framework in the coming months."

Comment: I’m having the same problem with .NET Framework 4.8 - the `System.Web.pdb` file downloaded from the symbol-server lacks source file information so even though I have the source of System.Web.dll *and* debug symbols for it for stack-traces, it won’t let me do source-stepping.

Answer (score -1):

It is indexed:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/indexedpdbs.txt

And you can find the project here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Services